# Overwrite nested z-index

Tags: css

I have an overlay which should be on top of everything. The problem is that the overlay is inside a content-wrapper that has a `z-index` defined. This can't be changed. The logo has a `z-index` defined as well. This too, can't be changed.

[I've made a Fiddle which shows the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/az55211o/). Can this be done with pure CSS? My other idea is to move the overlay with Javascript, but all the CSS is currently also nested, so I need to change lots of CSS if I do so.

Comment: I genuinly dont understand the issue. Are you trying to re-set the ´.overlay´ zindex from 1000 to x?

Comment: Can't you move the `.logo` to the `.content` container? Or move the `.overlay` outside of the container?
It doesn't make sense to have the `.overlay` inside the `.content` if you want it to cover all the page..

Comment: my bad, I get it now. you want the overlay to cover the logo aswell

Comment: Yes @NachoDawg, exactly.. :)

Comment: I don't think this is possible with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this, when you `click` on 'btn' toggle some class to '.overlay', like this\

```
 $("button").on("click", function() {
    $(".overlay").toggle();
   $('.content').toggleClass('z-1000');
});
```

in your CSS:

```
.content.z-1000{
  z-index:1000;
}
```

hope this works for you. working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zk6ksLgw/)

Comment: You add a class that adds z-index:1000, but it already has z-index:1000. Otherwise, you removed position:fixed, which I can't remove... :-/

Comment: i have updated the fiddle and added positive fixed to it and still working, man thing is you need to override that z-index of parent, overlay has z-index 1000 but i added z-index to parent which had z-index 1, try to see the point here

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry, was a bit too fast there... :) I can't use it tho, because I'm animating. But thanks for your time.